# How to override standard C++ functions when testing in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, mocking, shim

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Unit Testing. My code is using `time()` function to generate some object names and thus it is hard to ensure consistent behavior when testing.

If it was C#, I could use shims as shown in the article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx "Getting started with shims" section.

Is there any technique how to redefine `time()` calls during my C++ unit test?

Comment: Use a macro `#define time(...) my_time(__VA_ARGS__)` Then define my_time however you'd like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is called mocking (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object).

Personally I like to use Hippomocks (https://github.com/dascandy/hippomocks) which allows in the current version to mock C and C++ functions (with the notable exception of non-virtual class methods, see for example [Mocking non-virtual methods in C++ without editing production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2339558/1945549)).

Comment: Thanks, Hippomocks almost worked for me. At first it failed to compile because Microsoft VC++ compiler did not like `new (this)`. Then I risked and just commented it out. Now the `time()` calls were mocked correctly in my unit test code, but unfortunately, in the code under test the default `time()` was called. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that my tested code is located in a separate static `.lib` or maybe I totally broke it when commented away `new (this)`, or maybe there are some problems with my header inclusion order. I'll inspect it further.

Comment: I don't know the exact mechanism used by Hippomocks' MockRepository::ExpectCallFunc to "intercept" a function but I have a similar setup having the testee part of a library statically linked against my unit test project. So I'm pretty sure this shall work.

Comment: Regarding new (this): What is the compilation failure symptom? Usually it is said that placement new requires #include <new> but in my setup the Hippomocks header compiles fine. Note that I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: It seems, I found a working solution. `time()` was defined as `static __inline time_t __CRTDECL time(time_t * _Time)
{
    return _time64(_Time);
}` in time.inl file, and for some reason Hippomocks could not mock it. But it works with `_time64`. About `new` - it was my fault, I have redefined it in some header for debugging purposes: `#define new new(_NORMAL_BLOCK,__FILE__, __LINE__)`. Now I rearranged my headers, uncommented `new (this)` back as it was and now `mocks.OnCallFunc(_time64).Return(0)` works as expected.

Comment: Inlined methods cannot be mocked as their is no possible "fake" call indirection to the mock. That it worked when calling `time()` from the test itself indicated that the compiler didn't inline it there. I'm glad it worked for you by mocking `_time64()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't "redefine" these things *per se*, but you can provide an alternative implementation under a different name, and make the distinction *almost transparent* in your real code.

**Typically, you *mock the function*.**

[CxxTest](http://cxxtest.com/) takes the approach of having you invoke `T::time()` instead of `std::time()` (which is close enough!); with macro/include tricks, that call will resolve either to `std::time()` or to whatever replacement implementation you provide.

Here's a much-simplified, incredibly naive example designed only to demonstrate the basic principle:

#### foo.h

```
#include "mocked-functions.h"

/**
 * Takes the current time as a UNIX timestamp, and divides it by 10.
 */
inline int foo()
{
   return T::time(NULL) / 10;
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
}
```

#### test.cpp

```
#define USE_MOCKS
#include "foo.h"
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
   mock_time_result = 50;
   assert(foo() == 5);

   mock_time_result = 400;
   assert(foo() == 40);
}
```

#### mocked-functions.h

```
#include <ctime>

#ifdef USE_MOCKS
   #include "mock-time.h"
#endif

namespace T {
   time_t time(time_t* ptr)
   {
      #ifdef USE_MOCKS
         return Mock_time(ptr);
      #else
         return std::time(ptr);
      #endif
   }
}
```

#### mock-time.h

```
#include <ctime>

time_t mock_time_result = 0;

time_t Mock_time(time_t* ptr)
{
   if (ptr) *ptr = mock_time_result
   return mock_time_result;
}
```

#### To run

```
$ g++ main.cpp -I. -o main
$ g++ test.cpp -I. -o test
$ ./main   # output is the real time div by 10
$ ./test   # output is nothing; all assertions succeed
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't include `ctime` or `time.h` then you may write whatever definition you want for `time()`

Comment: Unfortunately, the code to test must be compiled with `ctime` because there is no other reasons to redefine `time()` calls. It seems not good idea to redefine something in the original code just for unit testing needs. That's why I hoped that there is some trick to override C/C++ functions just in the scope of my unit testing code.

Comment: @Martin:  If a function is non-deterministic, you must mock it in your unit tests - which *is* redefining it in such a way that it *is* deterministic.

Comment: @Martin Why are "unit tests" not worth changing how the code works?  Untestable code is, in a sense, worse.  Making it testable is better.  Change calls to `time` to calls to `my_time`, then hook `my_time` up to `ctime` normally, and up to some deterministic system when doing unit tests?

Comment: This means that I'll have to do something like `if isTestMode` inside of `my_time`, and thus `my_time` function will be test-aware, which doesn't seem right. But you are right that I should redesign my code to be deterministic in some way (passing some flag etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing requires deterministic code.  `std::time()`, by definition, is non-deterministic.  This leaves you with 2 options:  1) Change how you are generating names to be deterministic, or 2) mock `std::time()`.

It seems your focus is on #2, so one of the easiest ways to do that is to wrap the call to `std::time()` behind your own function for name generation.

```
std::string generate_name(bool use_time = true)
{
    ...
    if (use_time)
    {
        // do something with time()
    }
    else
    {
        // return a value that is deterministic
    }
}
```

Your unit tests will pass in `false` for the `use_time` parameter.

You can avoid including `<ctime>` in your unit test code, and write your own version of `time()` to call for the unit tests (this is actually closer to the approach most TDD developers prefer).

Since you are not testing the functionality of `time`, but rather how you treat its output, an even better approach (the first option) would be to pass the output of `time` into the function you use to generate names.  This way, your unit tests can control the input and test the output, completely.

```
std::string generate_name(unsigned long long id)
{
    // do something to generate the name for the id
}

...

// production code
std::string name = generate_name(static_cast<unsigned long long>(std::time(NULL)));

// your unit test code could look like this
std::string name = generate_name(1ULL);
```